# PostGIS WMS raster data - pixel values shifted on different zoom levels

Tags: raster, postgis, leaflet, wms

I'm quite new to working with geo data, specifically with PostGIS and currently trying to understand the following phenomenon.

I have some raster data stored in a PostGIS database and use [this PgSQL function](https://gist.github.com/muety/9e3a6d0ad2bb5890c081670e0c4fc044) (taken from [this excellent book](http://www.postgis.us/chapter_17_edition_3)), without really understanding the details of it, to serve the rasters as PNG tiles through a WMS-compatible interface.

However, when visualizing the data on a map (Leaflet), the pixels seem to be somehow shifted by a couple of meters. Take a look at these two example screenshots.

**Zoom level 15:**
Here, the pixels correspond to the actual raw pixels in my raster.

[image]

**Zoom level 13:**
When zooming out a bit, apparently some kind of clustering happens and the pixels seem to be shifted to the north-west, where, in reality, no data should be present.

[image]

Can someone explain what is happening here? I assume the explanation is somewhere in the SQL function's code, as it obviously applies some kind of transformation to it instead of just returning raw data (probably the `ST_Resample` call).

Comment: WMS don't have zoom levels

Comment: Okay, I know, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: If the client (leaflet) is trying to force levels from a WMS. then some images will be stretched and some compressed.  The WMS also will generalise the raw data in it's creation of the image representation.